# Can I show a formula result in a pop-up window in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel

I am writing an Excel spreadsheet that includes a group of merged cells using a basic `=VLOOKUP()` formula to search for an item and return a description of that item (for example, selecting "apple" in the target cell would return something like "A red fruit" in the cell group). However, in many cases, the description is so long  that even with text wrapping, it still gets cut off at the end. I want to avoid just making the cells bigger or merging more cells into the group, because the area would have to be at least a dozen rows tall, and I only have so much room in that section to work with.

So my question is this: Is it possible to create a pop-up window (similar to a comment or data validation pop-up) that shows the full text of the formula result when the cell is selected?

Comment: Yes, you may show it in a comment. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can show the formulas result (i. e. the cell's value) of a selected cell in its comment.

If you place this in your **worksheets's code module**, it shows the value of each selected cell as comment. If you select another cell, the previous comment is deleted. Be aware: If you use regular comments additionally, they would get deleted with this code.

You can limit this functionality e. g. to a predefined range on your worksheet or to cells with formulas (see explanations in the code).

```
Option Explicit

Private cmt As Comment

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MonitoredCells As Range
    Dim c As Range

    ' Comments are shown as red triangle, all hidden by default:
    Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly

    ' Delete previous comment, if any
    If Not cmt Is Nothing Then cmt.Delete

    ' limit this functionality to e. g. columns A:C by this:
    Set MonitoredCells = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A:C"))
    If Not MonitoredCells Is Nothing Then
        Set c = MonitoredCells(1) ' Do it for the first selected cell only
        ' limit this functionality to cells with formulas:
        If c.HasFormula Then
            If c.Comment Is Nothing Then
                Set cmt = c.AddComment
            Else
                Set cmt = c.Comment
            End If
            cmt.Text Text:=CStr(c.Value)
            c.Comment.Visible = True
        End If
        Set c = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

If the cell's formula contains CHAR(10) line feeds, then try to autosize the comment by this:

```
cmt.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
```

If the autosized comment is one line only, then autosizing is not useful. In that case, you may extend it's size by following formula before showing it. The default size is 100.8 x 72 points. Following doubles the width and extends the height approximately to the necessary characters count, but at least to the default height:

```
cmt.Shape.Width = 200
cmt.Shape.Height = WorksheetFunction.Max(72, 0.35 * cmt.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Count)
```

Answer (score 0):

One answer would be to use VBA, and define your own function rule. This would allow you to use the `msgbox` command with your answer. However, the problem with functions that display popups, is that Excel will continue to recalculate ALL cells when something has been updated. This means each time you input a new value, your popup will appear again.

This can, and will, get very annoying.

By the way, this doesn't mean you can't turn off "Auto Recalculate," but this has it's own disadvantages.